# How can I coerce a UITextField to a list of numeric values?

Tags: ios, swift

I can restrict a UITextField to a CharacterSet such as strings, numbers, etc. But, how can I restrict, or even better coerce, the UITextField to a list of specific numeric values. Specifically I wish to only allow, or coerce to, [0.5, 1, 2, 4]

Comment: You can create a custom CharacterSet. but if you restrict for specifically [0.5], what should happen after the user typed 0?

Comment: In this case I hope to coerce 0 up to 0.5. I can see how I could create a custom CharacterSet for [1, 2, 4], but what about [0.5] as it is not a single character?

Comment: adding "0.5" to the CharacterSet will allow the user to enter for example "5.4". what you're describing is a unique behavior. there's nothing "out of the box" for you. you'll have to implement the logic in `textFieldShouldReplaceCharactersInRange` delegate function